# Accessing rows in a ListView

Tags: android

I'm having trouble changing the data held within a TextView inside of a listView.
I can access the data and send a toast of the text, but the list isn't updated when
I change it.

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, presidents));
    ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    ListAdapter list_adapter = lv.getAdapter();
    TextView var_x = (TextView) list_adapter.getView(0,null,null);
    ListView list = getListView();
    int count = list.getChildCount();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),(var_x).getText(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    var_x.setText("not a president");
}
```

How can I change the text/styling of a row once I've already created it?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, presidents)
setListAdapter(adapter);

// make the changes in the list

adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();  // refresh

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work..

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, ..., ...));

ListView resultList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.resultList);  
resultList.setAdapter(adapter);

TextView text = (TextView) adapter.getView(0, null, null); // as an example, use the first element in the list  

Spannable str = (Spannable) text.getText();  
str.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, str.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE); // whatever changes you want to make, this is just an example
```

Thanks,
Sen

Comment: Spannable str = (Spannable) text.getText();

Comment: causes an error. Are you assuming that I created R.id.resultlist somewhere else?  Is that statement effectively different than my call to getListView()?

Answer (score 0):

```
ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
adapter = new MyAdapter(this,R.layout.main,
            R.id.row_text,
            new String[]{"one", "two", "three"} );
list.setAdapter(adapter);

//Custom Adapter class

private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    String[] mStrings;
    LayoutInflater mInflater; 

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId,
            String[] strings) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, strings);
        mStrings = strings;
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) FirstAct.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.main,null, false);

        TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.row_text);
        text.setText(mStrings[position]);

        Spannable str = (Spannable) text.getText();
        str.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, str.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        return view;
    }

}
```

Hope this code will give you more idea (than the older one which is a bit complex), on how to get hold of each element in the list.
Just try and send me your comments.

Thanks,
Sen

Comment: Thanks again, I'm working on getting this code running.  I had a few questions.  Where does R.id.list come from, are you assuming I created it elsewhere?  Also, what is the FirstAct object?